slither: command not found
I was attempting to use Slither and I followed this guide: https://hackenproof.com/blog/for-hackers/how-to-use-slither-for-auditing-smart-contracts
My Docker installation is confirmed to work but when I try the slither command it's not found.
Any suggestions?
$ docker run hello-world

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

$ docker pull trailofbits/eth-security-toolbox
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from trailofbits/eth-security-toolbox
3713021b0277: Pull complete 
48f07fdb5713: Pull complete 
4f4fb700ef54: Pull complete 
d03b8fb1706d: Pull complete 
b156fc1f3fe3: Pull complete 
cb589d1c7ba6: Pull complete 
fea6ed6468da: Pull complete 
5c8210db5856: Pull complete 
8e5268f67d62: Pull complete 
d8d1dafd1ed3: Pull complete 
5c1331ca8c47: Pull complete 
55772d8db702: Pull complete 
1eada916d256: Pull complete 
7e8bd32f71fb: Pull complete 
de686c70a786: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:0e3a342b4784b4627d83bee4df4aefd2b387aaaeed2096b2f12909291e5238f9
Status: Downloaded newer image for trailofbits/eth-security-toolbox:latest
docker.io/trailofbits/eth-security-toolbox:latest
$ slither --version
slither: command not found


Since, you’ve installed slither using docker, so you need to create and start the container as well, using docker run command.
Also, you need to copy the contract file that you want to analyze using slither, to the corresponding container environment, so as to run the slither commands.
You can follow this tutorial.
